# Can't, for the life of me, find where this .as file is being referenced

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a client for whom I am updating a website... the previous designer created everything in flash with .as files imported that reference xml content for some of the stuff.  unfortunately, this does not help my situation, as they did not use xml for the whole site.

here's the problem:  there's a navigational block that is defined by a .as file that i found in the required directory.  i found the content in it.  i reconfigured the function that defines it to suit my needs (ie, reordering+renaming the items found therein), saved it, exported to .swf and still nothing!  i have no idea what is going on... i look in the library under the linkage menu and can't see it anywhere.  i look in all the relevant files that are linked and nothing references it, or the function that contains it.  is there something i am missing here?  do i need to setup a master .as import directory in a preference or something?  is it just already imported and hidden somewhere in the .fla file?  i'm drawing a blank.

my client wants me to fix it and is wary that the prev. designer won't give up their method to keep them as a client.  please help.  thanks!

Comment: I hope you get a useful answer to your question. I don't have an answer, but a comment: Every time I have had a client who said, "I don't want to ask the previous (contractor)" for some required content, it turned out it was *actually* because said client had not paid said previous contractor. I should add that it's only happened twice to me, so that's hardly a representative sample. I should also point out I ended up dumping both clients not long thereafter.

Comment: no worries, this guy's good for it. we have a solid working relationship and i get paid.  i've done work for him already.  and... i think i am about to answer my own question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, here's the deal... make sure that no library items are clicked when looking at the properties box. the class was being referenced by the movie itself and i had to click outside of the stage to see it.  go figure, it's always something simple.  now to make this thing behave! ;)